# Dropna By Column by levels in multiindex and swap for non-na values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I am trying to do some transformations and kind of stuck. Hopefully somebody, can help me out here.

```py
l0    a         b         c         d       e         f      
l1    1     2   1   2     1     2   1   2   1   2     1     2
0   NaN   NaN NaN NaN  93.4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  19.0  28.9
1   NaN   9.0 NaN NaN  43.5  32.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN   3.4
2   NaN   5.0 NaN NaN  93.3  83.6 NaN NaN NaN NaN  59.5  28.2
3   NaN  19.6 NaN NaN  72.8  47.4 NaN NaN NaN NaN  31.5  67.2
4   NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN  62.5 NaN NaN NaN NaN   NaN   1.8
```

I have a dataframe, (shown above), and as u can see that, there are multiple 'NaN' with an multiindex column. Selecting the columns along level = 0 (i.e. `l0`)

1. I would like to drop the entire column if *all are NaN*. so, in this case the column's

```py
l0 = ['b', 'd', 'e'] # drop-cols
```

should be dropped from the Dataframe

```py
l0    a           c           f      
l1    1     2     1     2     1     2
0   NaN   NaN  93.4   NaN  19.0  28.9
1   NaN   9.0  43.5  32.0   NaN   3.4
2   NaN   5.0  93.3  83.6  59.5  28.2
3   NaN  19.6  72.8  47.4  31.5  67.2
4   NaN   NaN   NaN  62.5   NaN   1.8
```

2. This will give me the dataframe (as shown above). **I would like to then `slide` values along the rows if all the entries before are null (or swap values between adjacent cols). e.g. Looking at index = `0` i.e. first row.**

```py
l0    a           c           f      
l1    1     2     1     2     1     2
0   NaN   NaN  93.4   NaN  19.0  28.9
```

Since, all the values in `col - a` are null. 
I would like to slide / swap values first b/w `col - a` and `col - c`.
and then receprocate the same for columns along the `right-side` i.e. replace entries in `col-c` with `col-f` and make all entries in `col-f`, `NaN` giving me

```py
l0    a           c           f      
l1    1     2     1     2     1     2
0   93.4   NaN  19.0  28.9  NaN   NaN
```

This is really to save memory for processing and storing information, as interchainging labels `['a', 'b', 'c'...]` does not change the meaning of the data.

**EDIT: Any Idea's for (2)**

I have managed to solve (1) with the following code:

```py
for c in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
  if df[c].isna().all().all():
    df = df.drop(columns=[c])
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `all`

```
s=df.isnull().all(level=0,axis=1).all()
df.drop(s.index[s],axis=1,level=0)
Out[55]: 
     a           c           f      
     1     2     1     2     1     2
l1                                  
0  NaN   NaN  93.4   NaN  19.0  28.9
1  NaN   9.0  43.5  32.0   NaN   3.4
2  NaN   5.0  93.3  83.6  59.5  28.2
3  NaN  19.6  72.8  47.4  31.5  67.2
4  NaN   NaN   NaN  62.5   NaN   1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `groupby` and `filter`

```
df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).filter(lambda d: ~d.isna().all().all())

    a           c           f      
    1     2     1     2     1     2
0 NaN   NaN  93.4   NaN  19.0  28.9
1 NaN   9.0  43.5  32.0   NaN   3.4
2 NaN   5.0  93.3  83.6  59.5  28.2
3 NaN  19.6  72.8  47.4  31.5  67.2
4 NaN   NaN   NaN  62.5   NaN   1.8
```

A little bit shorter

```
df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).filter(lambda d: ~np.all(d.isna()))
```